# how can i fill in using xpath in cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, automated-tests, ui-automation

i have a scenario where all the text fields are having common ids.i want to fill in those using xpath as i can access them only using `contains` method of xpath .for eg:
`tr[td//text()[contains(., 'account1')]]/td[3]/a[4]"`

i have also googled but didnt got any reliable answer.i want to **fill in text box using xpath**.is it possible??.moreover i even tried a new `web-step` such as :

```
When /^I fill in xpath "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)" for id "([^"]*)"$/ do |xpath,value|
  find(:xpath, xpath).set "value"
end
```

.i have also tried to use `within` method such as:-

```
within(:xpath, xpath) do
```

any suggestions????

Answer (score 0):

`id` is for unique identification. Several common ids in same page is a big No No.

You need change the situation instead of adapting to it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the person above.  You really should never use XPATH.  First off, it's extremely brittle and hard to read when you're debugging your code.  Instead, I'd use css selectors.  Sure, it's more of a hassle, but it's easier to debug.  If you're having problems with scoping, just do a within block...it'd look something like this:

```
When /^ I fill in <code> with <text> $/ do |code,text|
  within('.css') do 
    fill_in(:css, " ", :with => "text") 
  end 
end
```